# Depth testing doesn't work when using custom framebuffer

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer, depth-testing, qopenglfunctions

I'm stydying framebuffers and I've made a mirror in my scene. It works fine except the depth testing. Got stuck trying to make it work. (when rendering to default frame buffer - depth testing works fine). Would appreciate any help. Here is the code:

```
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

glViewport( 0, 0, 512, 512 );

unsigned int fbo;
glGenFramebuffers( 1, &fbo );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo );

unsigned int rbo;
glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &rbo );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo );
glRenderbufferStorage( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH, 512, 512 );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0 );

glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, 
GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo ); //if remove this, mirror works but without depth test
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
this->mirror->texturePack[0]->textureId(), 0 ); 

//render scene from mirror camera

glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
glViewport( 0, 0, this->width(), this->height() );

//render scene from main camera
```

Comment: Yes, I did, it passed the check.

Comment: Are you sure? I tested the code and it failed. But if I change `GL_DEPTH` to `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32` it works.

Comment: Yes, I've also changed GL_DEPTH to GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, otherwise it doesn't pass this check. But my mirror still won't work. I've also tryed DEPTH_COMPONENT16, DEPTH_COMPONENT24, didn't help either. May be the error is somewhere in my rendeing code..

Comment: The code snippet of the question is fine (except `GL_DEPTH`). So the issue is somwhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it finally. I've added the glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT ) command right after binding mirror framebuffer and after that it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your farme buffer is inclomplete, because `GL_DEPTH` is no valid internal format for a render buffer storage.
 See [`glRenderbufferStorage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glRenderbufferStorage.xhtml). Try `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16`, `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` or `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32`:

```
glRenderbufferStorage( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 512, 512 );
```

See [OpenGL 4.6 core profile specification, 9.4 Framebuffer Completeness, page 323](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> The internal formats of the attached images can affect the completeness of
>   the framebuffer, so it is useful to first define the relationship between the internal
>   format of an image and the attachment points to which it can be attached.
>
> • An internal format is depth-renderable if it is DEPTH_COMPONENT or one
>   of the formats from table 8.13 whose base internal format is DEPTH_-
>   COMPONENT or DEPTH_STENCIL. No other formats are depth-renderable.

Note, the framebuffer completeness can be checked by:

```
glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried DEPTH_COMPONENT16, DEPTH_COMPONENT24 or DEPTH_COMPONENT32 and it passed glCheckFramebufferStatus check, but it still doesn't show the mirror texture.